# How to force min-height on table

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h2JCW/) code :

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:415px">
    <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td style="font-family:Arial;min-height:60px;font-size:12px;line-height:14px;">
                This is my text that I need in 2 lines
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
            <td style="font-size:12px;line-height:14px">
                Second Line
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, the first tr/td should be height 60px (`min-height:60px`) but in fact it isn't.

For many reasons, I can't use height directly (this code is formatted trought back office system, in a newsletter).

So, how can I take the whole height on the td trought min-height?

Also, tried putting `min-height:60px;` on tr, but nothing change...

Comment: What happens if you put a div inside the td and put the min-height on it?

Comment: I can't! Outlook erase div...! I need table...

Answer (score 39):

`min-height` [doesn't work for table elements:](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html)

> In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-width' and 'max-width' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table columns, and column groups is undefined.

I can only assume this applies to `td` and `tr` as well.

What should always work is wrapping the content in a div, and applying `min-height` to that,  as shown in [this JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/h2JCW/4/)

```
 <td style="font-family:Arial;min-height:60px;font-size:12px;line-height:14px;">
            <div style="min-height: 60px; background-color: green">
            This is my text that I need in 2 lines
            </div>
        </td>
```

**Edit:** You say this doesn't work with Outlook.

Alternative idea: Place a 60 px tall image in the  `td`, and make it `float: left`:

```
<td>
  <img src="..." style="float: left">
</td>
```

Comment: @markzzz then I don't think you can do this - except you can try a `<p>` instead. Otherwise, I think  `height` is the only way to go

Comment: Really? Damn, I need to do it... :( Can't use height...! `<p>` get the min-height?

Comment: @markzzz you can try `<p>` but chances are outlook will mess that up as well, if it breaks `<div>`s....

Comment: Tried on <p>, and yes they are also cutted! The image example looks great, but too complicated! Also, I'm sure float:left is cutted...so it won't work.. :(

Comment: @markzz I would try the image if I were you (alternatively with `align="left"` - I can't think of a better way.

Comment: css doesn't disappoint me, this is what i expected from css. torture

Comment: The old school way to do this before CSS layouts was to add columns with a spacer image in it. 

<tr><td>[spacer img]</td><td>[content]</td><td>[spacer img]</td></tr>

The downside is that if images aren't loaded the spacer images will shop up in the layout.

Answer (score 26):

### Use `<td height="60">` not CSS height or min-height

For HTML email set your table cell as `<td height="60">` and it will treat that as the min-height. If your content is more than 60px, it will expand accordingly.

Comment: Not only email, but for all the tables, and in css too

Comment: This should be the correct answer to make it work in Outlook/emails

Comment: Boom! Works beautifully. `height` is the new `min-height` for tables. :)

Comment: This fixes my issues with height inconsistencies in Outlook 2013! :)

Comment: this is deprecated now

Answer (score 11):

Put a DIV in the cell, style the DIV instead.

Answer (score 9):

**Min-height doesn't works on tables.**

It is sometimes useful to constrain the height of elements to a certain range. Two properties offer this functionality: `min-height` & `max-height`

But these can't be used on non-replaced inline elements, table columns, and column groups.

Answer (score 6):

You can't set **min-height** and **min-width**, but you can use some CSS3 for achievements this same effect.

```css
.default-table table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.default-table table td {
  padding: 0;
}

.default-table tr:before {
  width: 0px;
  content: '';
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 28px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.default-table {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="default-table">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Steve</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>stevesmith@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jone</td>
        <td>Polanski</td>
        <td>jonep@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

but if u having collapse or padding in td. You must give for .default-table table minus margin-left.

Answer (score 3):

HTML :

```
<table></table>
```

CSS :

```
table{
    height:0px; /*Set any facultative length value to Height (percentage value doesn't work)*/
    min-height:100vh;
}
```

That's how I always resolve this problem ...

Comment: Best answer! Thx. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add display block

```
<td style="font-family:Arial;min-height:60px;font-size:12px;line-height:14px;display:block;">
```

Comment: He asked how to force it on the cell hence I provided this answer. Of course using another tag within the TD is the right approach but I answered his question correctly imo

Answer (score 2):

**Here's a solution that works in Outlook** (tested) and other e-mail clients:

```
<td style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:300px;">&nbsp;</td>
```

This is cleaner than using an image, which could negatively affect your spam score, and does the exact same thing.

If you have other content in the `<td>` that you don't want to have that line height, you can just wrap the non-breaking space in a `<span>` and set the `line-height` on that tag:

```
<td><span style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:300px">&nbsp;</span>**Other content without 300px line-height here**</td>
```

The reason `height` or `min-height` works on `<div>` tags and not `<td>` is because `<td>` are set to `display:table-cell` and do not respect `height` the same way that `display:block` (`<div>`) elements do.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue by adding `display:block;` to its style as

```
<td style="display:block; min-height:200px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

min-height does not work in td, Set height that will work like min-height and automatic increase height if needed. That is worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not depend on the height in pixels. It works in all email clients:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:415px">
<tbody>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;line-height:14px;">
            This is my text that I need in 2 lines
        </td>
        <td style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;line-height:14px;">
            <br/>&#xfeff;<br/>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr valign="top">
        <td style="font-size:12px;line-height:14px">
            Second Line
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The solution works by adding a zero-width column with two lines to the right of the first one. It uses the &#xfeff; character, which is a non-breaking zero-width space.

Answer (score 0):

It may be reviving a 2012 post, for those who searched and found this post like me:

> **Note:** Check these addresses for the email client support before using this method, at the time of writing this answer, the support was around 50% -ish.
>
> [E-mail client support range of *:first-child*](http://caniemail.com/search/?s=%3Afirst-child)
>
> [E-mail client support range of *::before*](http://caniemail.com/search/?s=%3A%3Abefore)

```css
table tr:first-child td:before {
  min-height: 100px;
  display: block;
  content: ""
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't believe that pseudo element support is very good for many email clients.

Comment: Yes, it seems so. Shoud I remove the answer? https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=%3Afirst-child https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=%3A%3Abefore

Comment: Pseudo elements may work for some people's requirements. I think the idea of using them still has some value. It may be best to note the lack of support directly in your answer.

Answer (score -4):

What I found !!!, **In tables CSS** `td{height:60px;}` **works same as CSS** `td{height:60px;}`

Comment: This question was answered over 3 years ago by Pekka. Furthermore, The OP said "For many reasons, I can't use height directly". And in your answer you are using `height` directly.