# <li> stay size, when $.empty() - Without Display:block;

Tags: jquery, listitem

I've got a small problem, for what the problem is probably easy.. I guess i'm overlooking something.

Anyway, I'm creating an interactive form where users can click on `li` items, which get a 'tick' icon when they are clicked. However, for some reason, when you click the other `li` item, the size of the previous `li` gets to 1px..

I use `$.empty`, since the 'tick' is created by using the FontAwesome SVG icon library, by appending `<i class="fa fa-icon"></i>` to the clicked list item. However, to remove that tick, and append it to the newly clicked `li` item, I use Jquery `$.empty` .. Which makes the `li` item, tiny.

Check out this fiddle, to see what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/t6exT/9/

Hopefully someone can bring me a great solution. Thanks!

P.s. The solution cannot be `display:block;`, since I need `display:table;` for the 'tick' to be vertically (and horizontally) centered.

Comment: You should post your code along with the jsFiddle link, just incase the link becomes invalid.

Comment: I can't get the fiddle to actually do anything wherever I click

Comment: Hm, strange. I can click on the coloured boxes and the tick becomes in them. Click another one and the tick gets removed, including the size of the box..

Comment: Note the contents of the li before you add the icon to it.

Comment: `min-height` doesn't work for table elements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822082/how-to-force-min-height-on-table

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer Ah, got it:  at least in Firefox, the `li` elements aren't showing up at all without text in them.  I didn't have anything visible to click on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to force the boxing with a ::after pseudo-class.

i.e.

```
#questions li::after {
    display:table-cell;
    content: ''
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t6exT/11/

Answer (score 2):

`display:table` is causing the problem. Table does not take height if it is empty.

Write:

```
#questions li {
    display:inline-block;
}
li i.fa {
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/t6exT/15/)